# Tag what time each word in textarea was typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like, with Javascript, to tag what time each word in a textarea was typed.

I am aware that it may sound strange, but it is for a dictaphone application I create.

One way, I think, is to use "onchange" and log each time the user press space and create an array, for example (each value is a word).

```
[0] => "2015-04-23 09:00:04", [1] => "2015-04-23 09:00:05", [2] => "2015-04-23 09:00:09"
```

The problem is what happens if a person use the delete button or backspace. Then this method will crash.

Do you have any ideas how to do?

Comment: Paste some code. Why/how delete button crash?

Comment: block the use of backspace and delete :D

Comment: If the text can be edited you might need to try a different approach, like logging diffs instead of word dates. e.g. http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

Answer (score 1):

You can detect which key is pressed, and then edit the array accordingly:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        // Backspace
        case 8:
            // Remove word from array if necessary
            break;

        // Delete button
        case 46:
            // Remove word from array if necessary
            break;

        // Anything else
        default:
            // Add timestamp to array
            break;
    };
});
```

In this example code, it won't add timestamps to your array for the backspace or delete buttons.